# Get each element's attribute through $.each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to do `$('div').attr('data', 'ip')` through  a `.each()` just returns `undefined`.

Let's say I have 4 divs

```
    <div class="box" data-ip="ipvalue">content</div>
    <div class="box" data-ip="ipvalue">content</div>
    <div class="box" data-ip="ipvalue">content</div>
    <div class="box" data-ip="ipvalue">content</div>
```

and I need to iterate each one and get the data-ip value.

My code, it just returns undefined (server, serverObj, are variables).

```
var serversObj = $('.server');
serversObj.each(function(index, el) {
    return $(this).data('ip');
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where is your 'server' in html?

Comment: $('div').attr('data-ip'); try it.

Comment: *"What am I doing wrong?"* `.each` is for iterating over the elements, it ignores the return value of the callback (unless it is `false`). Before you use a jQuery method you are not very familiar with, I recommend to read [**its documentation**](https://api.jquery.com/each/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what the code should be for the markup sample you gave.

```
var serversObj = $('.box'),
Ipvals = [];
serversObj.each(function(index, el) {
    Ipvals.push( $(this).data('ip'));
});
console.log( Ipvals);
```

You can also use $.map() to return the same array.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use map if you want to get all of the values of all of the elements

```
var ips = $(".box")  //get all of the elements
              .map( 
                  function(){ 
                      return $(this).data("ip"); //get the value from the attribute
                  }
              ).get();  //returns an Array
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/STg8g/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.box').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('data-ip'));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, this is totally wrong:

```
$('div').attr('data', 'ip')
```

This is setting an attribute called `data` to a value of `"ip"`, it does nothing involving data attributes. Effectively, you're doing this: `<div data='ip'>`.

If you want to access a data attribute called `data-ip`, you want

```
$('div').data('ip')
```

If you want to access it for a series of elements, you can't just `return` it out of a `.each` loop. That value is discarded. You need to `map` your input set of elements to a set of outputs:

```
$('.server').map(function () { return $(this).data('ip') })
```

This will produce an array that has each element matched by `.server`'s `data-ip` attribute.